# Question on proving $γ∨ρ=γ∘ρ∘γ$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, semigroups

[image]

in theorem 5 of [Group congruences on eventually regular semigroups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/37D0D5EC86B3D13A66BDC65AEA2E326D/S1446788700031025a.pdf/group_congruences_on_eventually_regular_semigroups.pdf) by S. Hanumantha Rao. he saied it suffices to prove $ρ∘γ∘ρ⊆γ∘ρ∘γ$. Why?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is your general definition for the join of two congruences, but in any algebra the join of two congruences $\gamma$ and $\rho$ (or indeed, in any set the join of those equivalence relations) is given by
$$\gamma \vee \rho = \bigcup_{n\geq 1}(\gamma \circ \rho)^n.$$
Now, if $\rho \circ \gamma \circ \rho \subseteq \gamma \circ \rho \circ \gamma$, then
\begin{align}
(\gamma \circ \rho \circ \gamma)^2
&=\gamma \circ \rho \circ \gamma \circ \gamma \circ \rho \circ \gamma\\
&=\gamma \circ \rho \circ \gamma \circ \rho \circ \gamma\\
&\subseteq \gamma \circ \gamma \circ \rho \circ \gamma \circ \gamma\\
&=\gamma \circ \rho \circ \gamma,
\end{align}
whence $(\gamma \circ \rho \circ \gamma)^n=\gamma \circ \rho \circ \gamma$, for all $n\geq1$, by induction, yielding
$$\gamma \vee \rho = \bigcup_{n \geq 1} (\gamma \circ \rho)^n \subseteq \bigcup_{n\geq 1} (\gamma \circ \rho \circ \gamma)^n = \gamma \circ \rho \circ \gamma,$$
while the reverse inclusions is obvious.

I hope you can justify the several steps.
For example, I'm using the fact that composition of binary relations is associative.
In several ones I use $\gamma \circ \gamma = \gamma$, where one inclusion follows from transitivity, while the other follows from reflexivity.
In general, for two binary relations, $\alpha$ and $\beta$, if $\alpha$ is reflexive, then $\alpha \subseteq \alpha \circ \beta$.
I think these hints justify all the steps.
Let me know if you still have any doubts.